# BroadcastDispatcher finish event only called once (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, voice

I'm trying to make a LoFi Radio for Discord. Whenever the bot goes online, it joins every channel named lofi on a server (this is very badly coded and won't work if there's more than two lofi channels in one server I know, will fix later.) The problem I'm having is the broadcast dispatcher's finish event is only called once. I want it to play a new random song every time the last one stops, but it only plays one when it goes online and one after that song, then the dispatcher is set to `null` which confuses me.

**Code:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var client = new Client();
var files = fs.readdirSync("./mp3/");

var broadcast;
var curSong;
var dispatcher;

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`------------${client.user.tag}------------\n`);

    curSong = `./mp3/${files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]}`;
    broadcast = client.voice.createBroadcast();
    broadcast.play(curSong);
    broadcast.dispatcher.on("finish", () => {
        curSong = `./mp3/${files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]}`;
        broadcast.play(curSong);
        client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: curSong.split("/")[2].replace(".mp3", ""), type: "STREAMING", url: "https://twitch.tv/TwitchChannel" }, status: "Online" });
    });

    client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: curSong.split("/")[2].replace(".mp3", ""), type: "STREAMING", url: "https://twitch.tv/TwitchChannel" }, status: "Online" });

    client.channels.cache.array().forEach((chnl) => {
        if(chnl.name.toLowerCase() == "lofi") {
            chnl.join().then(connection => {
                connection.play(broadcast);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a function inside the ready event of the client.

**This is the code for the entire bot (excluding login & message event)**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var client = new Client();
var files = fs.readdirSync("./mp3/");

var broadcast;
var curSong;
var dispatcher;

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`------------${client.user.tag}------------\n`);

    curSong = `./mp3/${files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]}`;
    broadcast = client.voice.createBroadcast();
    broadcast.play(curSong);
    dispatcherLol();

    client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: curSong.split("/")[2].replace(".mp3", ""), type: "STREAMING", url: "https://twitch.tv/AtlasDevelopment" }, status: "Online" });

    client.channels.cache.array().forEach((chnl) => {
        if(chnl.name.toLowerCase() == "lofi") {
            chnl.join().then(connection => {
                connection.play(broadcast);
            });
        }
    });

    function dispatcherLol() {
        broadcast.dispatcher.on("finish", () => {
            curSong = `./mp3/${files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]}`;
            broadcast.play(curSong);
            client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: curSong.split("/")[2].replace(".mp3", ""), type: "STREAMING", url: "https://twitch.tv/AtlasDevelopment" }, status: "Online" });
            dispatcherLol();
        });
        return;
    }
});
```